# Laravel 4: one to many by on multiple columns?

Tags: laravel, relational-database

I'm making a table that essentially maps rows in a table to rows in another table where the structures are as follows:

```
|--- Words --|   |- Synonyms -|
|------------|   |------------|
| id         |   | id         |
| en         |   | word_id    |
| ko         |   | synonym_id |
| created_at |   | created_at |
| updated_at |   | updated_at |
|------------|   |------------|
```

Now then, I know I can essentially have the `words` model have many `Synonyms` through a function like:

```
public function synonyms()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Synonym');
}
```

No problem, but this method always gets it by the the `word_id`, and I would like to get it from `word_id` **OR** `synonym_id` that way I don't have to make multiple entries in the DB.

Is there anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check laravel docs Eloquent relationships. It would only get word_id because that's the only foreign key I believe.

Also why do you have synonym_id in your Synonyms table?

Comment: I know it would get only the word_id, I was hoping it could get both. I have a synonym_id because it shows whiich word is a synonym with another word. IE, Photo(id 1) and Photograph(id 100) so the row is like id:1,word_id:1,synonym_id:100 but as a result we know photograph is a synonym of photo, and I would like to avoid making and extra row, id:2,word_id:100,synonym_id:1 Did I approach my table wrong perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for polymorphic relationship.

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations

Comment: I understand polymorphic to be for relations that may be on many tables, this is for multiple columns on the same table, would it work the same? Also if you feel there is a better way to do the table, I'm not opposed to changing it.

Answer (score -1):

I think your best bet is to create a many-to-many relationship with `words` on itself using the `synonyms` table as your pivot table.

Add this to your `Word` model.

```
public function synonyms()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Word', 'synonyms', 'user_id', 'synonym_id');
}
```

Using it:

```
$word = Word::where('en', '=', 'someword')->first();
foreach($word->synonyms as $synonym) {
    // This method would probably return the same word as a synonym of itself so we can skip that iteration.
    if($synonym->en == $word->en) {
        continue;
    }
    // Echo the synonym.
    echo $synonym->en;
}
```

I'm a bit confused on you wanting to be able to find synonyms by the `word_id` or `synonym_id` but I think if you are using the many-to-many, it won't matter because if you know the synonym, it's still technically just a word, and you'd do the exact same thing.

Comment: I'm not in a place where I can test this at the moment, but it looks promising. The reason I want to use either column is because lets say I have decided photo(1) has a synonym which is picture(57). Now then the row would be like (id:3,word_id:1,synonym_id:57) but this also means that a synonym for picture is photo. So I would have to always make a second row if I wanted it to work using only word_id. Is there a better way to do this?